# IE min-height Hover Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, hover

I have a grid of li's each with a hover. It works completely fine in all othe browser except Internet Explorer (testing on IE10). The hover expand the div beyond its height. I know that IE has issues on min-height but as far as I know this should be supported.

I have tried everything I can find including:-

1. setting body, html to 100%
2. setting the parent ul and li to position: relative
3. Adding vertical-align top to the li
4. Adding min-height: 0px to the parent ul
5. Adding display inline block to li and/or ul
6. The following hack

   min-height: 236px;
    height:auto !important;
    height: 236px;

None of these work.

The only thing that does work is removing the min-height altogether and setting a fixed height property and then a height auto in a media query. I can live with this, but I'd really like to know what could fix this annoying behaviour.

Thanks

Glennyboy

Comment: Could you make a repro on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: If you have "box-sizing" other than "content-box" on that item with "min-height", try to change it to that. It helped in my case.